# PHP need to count how many instaneces of specific value in array

Tags: php, json, loops, object, count

I have a JSON file which structure looks like this (very simplified):

```
[
  {
    "customerId": "M12345",
    "houses": [
      {
        "id": "OBJ12345_1731321200",
        "status": {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Sold"
        }
      ],
     "plots": [
      {
        "id": "OBJ12345_1771637082",
        "status": {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Sold"
        }
       ],
        "projects": [],
        "farms": [],
        "commercialPropertys": [],
        "condominiums": [],
        "foreignProperties": [],
        "premises": []
   }
]
```

I have figured out how to count how many "houses" or "plots" there is:

```
$content = file_get_contents('estateList/estateList.json');
$GetEstateList = json_decode($content);
count($GetEstateList[0]["houses"]);
count($GetEstateList[0]["plots"]);
```

BUT Trying to figure out using php how to count how many objects which have a condition status(id:4)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Maybe I'm wrong, but have you tried something like `count($GetEstateList[0]["houses"]["status"]["id"]);` or `count($GetEstateList[0]["plots"]["status"]["id"]);`?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look at this but it's not working...and that would only count all instances of status, not where id = 4, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself...
Maybe not the "correct" way but it works! :)
Feel free to comment on any improvement or modifications...

```
$StatusCount = 0;
   foreach ($GetEstateList[0] as $GetEstateType) { 
      foreach ($GetEstateType as $GetEstate) { 
         if ($GetEstate["status"]["id"] == "4") {
            $StatusCount++;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a loop in order to count the objects, i would use a foreach loop, bellow is an example :

```
$count = 0;
foreach ( $GetEstateList[0] as $key => $value){
    if (isset($value['status']) && $value['status']['id'] === "4") {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is stuck on the missing parameter *status*, because that attribute is only contained inside *houses* and *plots* sections, also we can think that another cycle for each section will be needed

Comment: @xKobalt, modified the answer so it does not get stuck.I just answered the question, i think the small details are up to the op to solve so he also learns how things work.By providing all information he just needs to copy the code to run but if he debugs it a bit he will also learn how it runs. right?

Comment: It's a more performant code, but it's still not working properly, because it's searching for `$GetEstateList[0]["status"]` that does not exist. Before the *status*, OP needs *houses* or *plots* indexes, but there can be more elements inside them. So 2 more cycles (I think not only one) are needed --- Anyway it's true that an user that asks a question should learn about others code, but providing something that effectively works is more productive and easy to understand, in fact StackOverflow is done to help others with them programming issues, debug and documentation should belong to OP doings

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look at this but it's not working...

Comment: @djsringup, i have edited the answer, now it should work.

Comment: If I alter your code to: $GetEstateList[0]["houses"]
it works, but it only counts houses...

   $count = 0;
   foreach ( $GetEstateList[0]["houses"] as $key => $value){
       if (isset($value['status']) && $value['status']['id'] === "4") {
           $count++;
       }
   }

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to enter the `GetEstateList` array, then you need to do a cycle for each type (for now types showed are *plots* and *houses*), then you need another cycle, because each type is an array of elements and can have more than one estate.

So, try this code:

```
// Counter variable for condition expressed after (status == 4)
$counter = 0;

// Enter the array and get `customerId`, `houses` and `plots`,
// but we only need the types of estate, so only `houses` and `plots`, in this case
foreach ( $GetEstateList as $estate_array => $array_attr ) {

    // We only need `houses` and `plots` (increasing algorithm performance)
    if ( $array_attr == "houses" || $array_attr == "plots" ) {
        
        // We're checking all types of estates (all `houses` and all `plots`)
        foreach ( $array_attr as $type => $parameter ) {

            // So, we can get `status` of every estate
            if ( $parameter == "status") {

                // And finally we can get `id` for each estate `status`
                if ( $parameter["id"] == "4" ) {

                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Notice**: the code above cannot work if the written JSON structure is too different from the original.

Comment: Looks good but returns 0
Would it be a problem if there is more objects (some empty), updated the original question with the empty values

Comment: Logically it's not a problem, I improved the algorithm to increase its performance. Anyway, it's strange this is giving you `0`, can you try to perform `echo count($GetEstateList[0]["houses"]["status"]["id"]);` with `id` equal to 4 and check if you get `1`?

Comment: echo count($GetEstateList[0]["houses"]["status"]["id"] === 4); // Returned 1

Comment: Well... now can you try to perform `echo count($GetEstateList[1]["houses"]["status"]["id"]);` with `id` equal to 4? I think the problem is the index, but I want to be sure

Comment: count($GetEstateList[1]["houses"]["status"]["id"] === "4") // Still Returns 1